# What is the fastest speed you can ride a bicycle on wet roads without getting wet?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, estimation, centrifugal-force

Optimum speed without getting a line of muddy water splashing onto your back?

- no mud guards
- 26 inch wheels
- surface water on the road

calculations to be based on my shirt and shorts remaining dry
standard dimensions of an adult bike frame.

I am riding a bike and the water is being thrown upwards off the back tyre onto my back.

The question refers to the initial speed water drops should have when they leave the tyre to be able to reach my back when I am cycling during a rainy day

It does not refer to water splash when riding through a water on the road

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the angle at which water is splashed when a vehicle tyre rides in water on the road?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36119/)

Comment: See [Maximum height of mud thrown from a wheel](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/mud.pdf) Whether or not you get splashed depends on your position relative to the wheel.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The linked question is asking about water being splashed sideways, out of the plane of the wheel, whereas this question is asking about splashing in the plane of the wheel.

Comment: I agree with @sammygerbil that this question should be reopened, for the reasons he has stated. The question of the speed at which water/mud is thrown towards the cyclist from the rear wheel is very interesting.